# Float right element inside Bootstrap 4 thumbnail works differently than Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class='img-thumbnail'>
    <img src="a.jpg" class='img-fluid'>
</div>
```

This is what I have in a html file with bootstrap 4 css. The image comes inside a nice box. When I add a h4 heading, that comes under the image inside the box as well.

```
<div class='img-thumbnail'>
    <img src="a.jpg" class='img-fluid'>
    <h4>filename:a.jpg</h4>
</div>
```

But when I float it right using bootstrap `.float-right` class or `style='float:right'` the element goes to right side but it comes out of thumbnail. Please help.

```
<div class='img-thumbnail'>
    <img src="a.jpg" class='img-fluid'>
    <h4 class='float-right'>filename:a.jpg</h4>
</div>
```

In bootstrap 3, `.pull-right` class is what was used and it puts it to the right properly still inside the thumbnail box.

Full Code

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <p class='lead'>LOL</p>
    <ul class='list-group'>
      <li class='list-group-item active'>Something 1</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>Something 2</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>Something 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='col-9'>
    <div class='img-thumbnail'>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/2000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" class='img-fluid'>
      <h4 class='float-right'>$9.99</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the difference in `img-thumbnail` from Bootstrap 3.x to 4.x:

**Bootstrap 4.x:**

```
.img-thumbnail {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Bootstrap 3.x:**

```
.img-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The difference is that 3.x used `display:inline-block`. So, to create the same effect in 4.x you can simply add `d-inline-block` to the `img-thumbnail`...

```
   <div class='img-thumbnail d-inline-block'>
      <img src=".." class='img-fluid'>
      <h4 class='float-right'>$9.99</h4>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/r75rriVhX3

Answer (score 0):

simply add a d-inline-block class with the class img-thumbnail.

here is the code.

```
<div class='img-thumbnail d-inline-block'>
    <img src="a.jpg" class='img-fluid'>
    <h4 class='float-right'>filename:a.jpg</h4>
</div>
```